# Set cell value based on filename that was copied

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large excel file (500+ sheets) where we store a daily report on each sheet, each sheet is used to supply data to one sheet and make graphs.

I am trying to make it so I can drop these reports into a folder, run a macro and then have these copied into the master file.  The main file is currently set to make the sheet name the value of A1.

My current problem is that I the value I need to put in A1 is only present in the file name, it is not located in any cell and I have no way of having it added to the report.

The file name of the report is like this - `"Daily report for September  21 , 2015.xls"`

The code I have will currently copy the file into the master file but I need to be able to change cell value A1 to 9/21/15 in this example using just the "September  21" from the file name.

Here is my current code

```
Sub test()

     Dim Wb1 As Workbook
     Dim Wb2 As Workbook
     Dim Filename As String
     Dim Path As String
     Path = "M:\TESTCOPY\"  'CHANGE PATH
     Filename = Dir(Path & "\*.xls")

     With Application
          .ScreenUpdating = False
          .EnableEvents = False
          .DisplayAlerts = False
     End With
     Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)
     Set Wb2 = ThisWorkbook
     Wb1.Sheets.Copy Before:=Wb2.Sheets("LAST")
     Wb1.Close False
     With Application
          .ScreenUpdating = True
          .EnableEvents = True
          .DisplayAlerts = True
     End With

End Sub
```

It would also be nice to be able to check if sheet 9/21/15 already exists and abort the copy and also be able to delete the worksheet after the copy is done.  I know I can use Kill but I am not sure where to place it to kill Wb1 in this code.

Thanks

Edit:

I have gotten something to work but it is rather crude due to my lack of knowledge.  I'd like it to be able to loop through the files in a folder if possible and learn how to get rid of the nested replace commands.  I could not figure out how to get trim to work correctly or if it works the same to remove the spaces in the middle of the string so that is the reason for the replace commands.

```
Sub CopyReport()
Dim Wb1 As Workbook
Dim Wb2 As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim Path As String
Dim FileDate As String
Path = "M:\TESTCOPY\"  'CHANGE PATH
Filename = Dir(Path & "\*.xls")
FileDate = Filename

'--------------------------------------------

        With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        End With
        Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)
        Set Wb2 = ThisWorkbook
        Wb1.Sheets.Copy Before:=Wb2.Sheets("LAST")
        Wb1.Close False
        With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        End With

        Cells(1, 1).Value = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Trim(Replace(Replace(FileDate, "Daily report for ", ""), ".xls", "")), ",", " "), "  ", " "), "  ", " "), " ", ",")
        Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
        Kill (Path & Filename)

        MsgBox Replace(Filename, ".xls", "") & " has been copied and deleted"

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you actually have a comma in the filename and if so, why is there a space before it?

Comment: Yes, that is how I receive the file.  I really have no control over the name of it or the content but the name is standardized.

Comment: The first step would be to show "Daily report for September  21 , 2015.xls" in A1. Are you able to do this right now?

Comment: Actually using my nested replace command I am able to put "September,21,2015" into A1 which updates the sheet name correctly.  I haven't been able to test it across all dates yet but I think it should be fine although I am not very happy with the nested replace command.

Answer (score 0):

I do this, try it

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Text As String
    Dim MyDate As Date
    Dim Data() As String
    Text = "Daily report for September  21 , 2015.xls"
    Text = Replace(Text, "Daily report for ", "")
    Text = Replace(Text, ".xls", "")
    Text = Replace(Text, ",", "")
    While InStr(Text, "  ")
        Text = Replace(Text, "  ", " ")
    Wend
    Data = Split(Text, " ")
    MyDate = DateValue((Data(1) & "/" & MonthToNumber(Data(0)) & "/" &     Data(2)))
End Sub
Function MonthToNumber(ByVal Mo As String) As Integer
    Select Case Mo
        Case "September"
            MonthToNumber = 9
        Exit Function
    End Select
End Function
```

Cheers

Comment: Does that require a case for each month then?

Comment: Yes, that will be 12 cases.